# Smart / pythonic way to find which columns contain / match another column

Tags: pandas, string, nested

My question title sounds like little cryptic so I hope the example makes it clear.

I have a value in column "FindMe", and I want to know if this is in either of the options of "Search1" or "Search2".  The logic I have works (though if its present in both search 1 & 2 I know I have an issue)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {"Search1":["one_two","two_ten", "five_ten"],
        "Search2":["three_four","one_four","two_twelve"],
        "FindMe":["three","one","nine"]}
df =pd.DataFrame(data)

df["Present1"] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x.FindMe) in str(x.Search1), axis =1)
df["Present2"] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x.FindMe) in str(x.Search2), axis =1)

df["Present"] = np.where(df.apply(lambda x: str(x.FindMe) in str(x.Search1), axis =1) ==1, 
df.Search1,
                np.where(df.apply(lambda x: str(x.FindMe) in str(x.Search2), axis =1) ==1, 
df.Search2,""))
print(df)
```

Like I say my "Present" column works as it should, returning the value of the column where its found.  In reality, I have far more columns that I need to check and so yes I can create nested where's but this feels like there should be a better solution.

Any thoughts?
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **list comprehension** would do the job

```
df['Present'] = [[s for s in l if w in s] for l, w in 
                    zip(df.filter(like='Search').to_numpy(), df['FindMe'])]
```

---

```
    Search1     Search2 FindMe       Present
0   one_two  three_four  three  [three_four]
1   two_ten    one_four    one    [one_four]
2  five_ten  two_twelve   nine            []
```

Comment: This wasn't working on my real data but when I tried to create the sample it worked.  I figured that the blanks I have in my data were being read as null values and I had to replace those with ""